# Reading CRUD wont show " marks

Tags: php, html

I have created a CRUD system for a contact form.

If i was to input speech marks ("") it will not input anything after and including the speechmarks

I use the VARCHAR datatype in the database and type=text in html

### Example

In image 1. I have inputted symbols and standard text. This is fine.

In image 2. I have placed the speech marks after the = sign.

As you can see all the symbols and text that was entered before does not show as the speech mark is before it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGU5T.jpg

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
   <label for="contact_name" class="form-label">Contact Name</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" value="<?= $data['record']['contact_name'] ?? '' ?>" placeholder="Enter Site Name" required><br>
     </div>
   <div class="col-12">
     <h6 for="contact_email">Contact Email</h6>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" value="<?= $data['record']['contact_email'] ?? '' ?>"  placeholder="Leave blank if none"><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <h6 for="contact_subject">Subject</h6>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_subject" name="contact_subject" value="<?= $data['record']['contact_subject'] ?? '' ?>" placeholder="Floor where Machine is Locatated"> <br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <h6 for="contact_message">Message</h6>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_message" name="contact_message" value="<?= $data['record']['contact_message'] ?? '' ?>" placeholder="Floor where Machine is Locatated"> <br><br>                    
    </div>
                    

    <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about when you `echo` existing values into the field when the form loads? If so, then obviously it won't show anything after double-quotes (`"`), because double-quotes are also used to close the `value` attribute in the HTML.

So for example if the output of `<?= $data['record']['contact_name'] ?? '' ?>` is `ABC "DEF"` then the final HTML input will look like this when it's received by your browser:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" value="ABC"DEF""  placeholder="Leave blank if none">
```

The browser will see `value="ABC"` and think that's the value of the field, because it interprets the `"` after `C` as the end of the `value` attribute's content.

To avoid this, you must HTML-encode your output, e.g.

```
<?= htmlspecialchars($data['record']['contact_name'] ?? '') ?>
```

which in my example would output `ABC&quot;DEF&quot;`, which will work correctly. Demo:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" value="ABC&quot;DEF&quot;">
```

**Important note**: You should be HTML-encoding any data you echo into your site rountinely anyway, to avoid the danger of XSS injection attacks.

Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: No worries. As I said, you should be doing this routinely anytime you output data into a HTML page from your database, or directly from user input.

Comment: Great to know, Thanks! Are you also aware of how to output data inside a text area. I tried it and nothing got outputted?

Comment: Well funnily enough you don't actually need to HTML-encode into a textarea because data within a textarea isn't parsed by the browser (it shows as plain text). But also, what _exactly_ did you try? Remember (or if you can't remember, just remember that there's always the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) to consult) that a textarea is a bit of an anomaly (compared to most other form inputs) and doesn't have a "value" attribute, and requires a closing tag. Instead you should echo the necessary content in between the opening and closing tags.

Comment: ``` <textarea rows="4" name="contact_message" id="mytextbox" value="<?php echo $data['record']['contact_message'] ?? ''?>"></textarea> ``` i just tried this didnt work

Comment: Ok. Well what did I just mention in my last comment? See also that documentation link for a very clear example. Hopefully the fix is now obvious...

Comment: Ahh yes, just seen the comment. What i did was close the opening tag and place the echo it and then close tag. This had worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use your browser's debugging tools to observe the actual HTML that you are emitting to the client.  There you will see the difference between something like this:

```
value="text without quotes"
```

and something like this:

```
value="text with "quotes""
```

From the perspective of the web browser's rendering engine, what would be the "value" of the `value` attribute in the latter example?  It would be simply `"text with "`, and everything afterward is just nonsense that gets ignored.

[HTML-encode your values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) before outputting them.  Something like this:

```
value="<?= htmlentities($data['record']['contact_name'] ?? '') ?>"
```

Which would then output as:

```
value="text with &quot;quotes&quot;"
```

Which is more meaningfully parsed by the browser's rendering engine.

Comment: Im sure this is correct, i have used the above answer. thank you for your efforts in writing this answer tho!